# How can I change style of package v-calendar in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, datepicker, vcalendar

I'm currently working on a project that contains Vue.js, and I have a need to develop a datepicker. To do this, I've decided to use the package *[v-calendar](https://vcalendar.io/)*.

I've been able to implement the component and works as expected out-of-the-box. However, I'm trying some customization like styles (following the documentation), but it just won't work of some cases, and I can't figure out why.

The idea is to achieve this:

[image]

I've been able to set the header style through setupCalendar. However, when I try to apply the style to the content, it won't change.
After searching further in the documentation, I've noticed that they were passing the style as attributes, to which I've tried to replicate without any success.

I also wanted to know, if it's possible to submit the received $attrs that are inherited by the father-component into the input? At the moment, I'm passing one by one using `input-props`, but is there a better approach?

Right now it's like this:

[image]

```
<template>
    <date-picker
        :attributes="attributes"
        v-model="date"
        :input-props="{
            id: $attrs.id,
            name: $attrs.name,
            class: 'input--default color--white',
            autocomplete: 'nope',
            readonly: true
        }"
    >
    </date-picker>
</template>

<script>
    // packages
    import { setupCalendar, DatePicker } from 'v-calendar'
    import 'v-calendar/lib/v-calendar.min.css';

    setupCalendar({
        locale: 'pt-PT',
        themeStyles: {
            wrapper: {
                fontSize: '17px',
                lineHeight: '21px',
                boxShadow: '5px 5px 10px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .10 )',
            },
            header: {
                color: '#f7890b',
                textTransform: 'capitalize'
            },
            weekdays: {
                color: '#ededed'
            },
        },
         attributes: [{
            contentStyle: {
                color: '#ff4d4d', // Red
                fontWeight: 600,
                fontSize: '10px',
            },
            popover: { color: 'yellow', },
            highlight: {
                backgroundColor: 'purple',
            },
        }]

    });

    export default {
        inheritAttrs: false,
        components: {
            DatePicker
        },
        data () {
            return {
                date: null,
                attributes: [{
                    contentStyle: {
                        color: '#ff4d4d', // Red
                        fontWeight: 600,
                        fontSize: '10px',
                    },
                    popover: { color: 'yellow', },
                    highlight: {
                        backgroundColor: 'purple',
                    },
                }]
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about v-calendar but another way is to try it with Chrome Dev Tools. Check what CSS classes does v-calendar have and override them in components style tag.

Comment: I tried, but the datepicker element disappears when it loses focus on iput

Comment: @martinho Are you able to do this ?

Comment: hi, ya, i manage to do. If I remember correctly, it was through the classes, but I'm not sure, I haven't been on this project for a while. And I haven't worked with this package for some time either. But I can try to figure it out and then I'll say something.

Answer (score 0):

If using vue-datepicker, you can change the CSS style adding this styles to your .css or in your view inside  `<style> ...</style>`

Here an example of the elements. I already use it to change the input as [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) style:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 1em 2em 2em;
}
input,
select {
  padding: 0.75em 0.5em;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  height: 2.5em;
}

.example {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0em 1em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

code,
pre {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.settings {
  margin: 2em 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  background: #eee;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.form-group label {
  font-size: 80%;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    attrs: [
        {
          highlight: {
            style: {
              borderRadius: "6px",
              // border: '1px solid #1982EF',
              backgroundColor: "#ccd6e0b3",
            },
            contentStyle: {
              fontWeight: "700",
            },
          },
          dates: new Date(),
        },
        {
          dot: {
            style: {
              backgroundColor: "#53af52",
              marginBottom: "3px",
            },
          },
          dates: [],
        },
        {
          dot: {
            style: {
              backgroundColor: "#f2a000",
              marginBottom: "3px",
            },
          },
          dates: [],
        },
      ],
```

//these kind of style supported in v-calendar and  we can use it like this.

Answer (score -1):

Place it in the template tag:

Place it in the script tag:

import Calendar from "v-calendar/lib/components/calendar.umd";

While assigning data variables:

attrs: [

```
    {
      highlight: {
        style: {
          borderRadius: '6px',
          border: '2px solid #1982EF'
        },
      },
      dates: new Date()
    },
    {
      dot: {
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#53af52',
          marginBottom: '3px',
        },
      },
      dates: [],
    },
    {
      dot: {
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#f2a000',
          marginBottom: '3px',
        },
      },
      excludeDates: null,
    },
    {
      content: {
        style: {
          display:'none !important'
        },
      },
      excludeDates: null,
    }
  ],
```

This attrs are passed to the v-calendar component as prop for handling style.

Comment: `<Calendar :attributes="attrs" is-expanded class="pb-2 h-100 border-0" />` is hidden. The two code parts are not formatted properly. A start is [using](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75686666/edit) four space indent.